# Can we create a table with timestamp suffix in the table name in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a table in MySQL which needs to have the timestamp suffixed in the table name. I'm trying the following SQL command to achieve the same.

Attempt1. - `create table somename-NOW() (id integer, title varchar(100));`

Attempt2. - `create table somename-@NOW() (id integer, title varchar(100));`

The above commands did not work for me.

Thank you

Comment: You can use `prepared statement` for that

Comment: I am doing it in the workbench, I can do it using the commands only, no code is involved

Comment: Apart from anything else a minus in an identifier name is not valid unless backticked.

Comment: I don't know what your use case is but you may want to have a look at [partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning.html). The schema you want to implement tends to become really hard to maintain.

Comment: This sounds like a really bad idea.  One rare occasions I've copied a table over with a timestamp for analysis.  However, such tables are not usually created in a production environment or on a regular basis.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a *really* bad idea.  I would advise you to insert into a single table with an additional column:

```
create table somename (
    id integer,
    title varchar(100),
    loadtime datetime default now(),
    key (loadtime, id)
);
```

You can then load into this table and separate the batches using the `loadtime` column.  Other capabilities, such as partitioning, may also be helpful.

Comment: Yes indeed but we had a use case to do that, but your seems perfect and makes complete sense.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Prepared Statement`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html) for the same.

Note: Use a `backtick` to make sure if it not a valid identifier. Also, if you simply use `NOW()` it will return `YYYY-MM-DD HH:ii:ss`, there is a space between date & time and it will be an issue for any query, so you can format it, in a friendly name whatever you want using `DATE_FORMAT` function.

```
SET @s:= CONCAT('create table `somename_', DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%y_%m_%dt%H_%i_%s'), '` (id integer, title varchar(100))');
PREPARE stmt3 FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt3;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt3;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set @your_date = now();
SET @sql = CONCAT("CREATE TABLE ",@your_date," as SELECT * FROM db1.table1");
PREPARE stmt from @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```